# In English grammar, what's the name of a phrase coming between commas describing the previous term?

Tags: grammar

Let me give you an example first to ask my question better:

- Jack, **the guy who met with me**, feels happy.

The phrase "the guy who met with me" is coming between commas and describing Jack. We can remove it and still we have a declarative sentence:

- Jack feels happy.

In English grammar, what's the name of a phrase coming between commas describing the previous term?

Comment: That is an [appositive](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/appositives.html) phrase (not a sentence).

Comment: Thank you @Jeffery I made a correction with Phrase replacing the sentence. You are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's called a [non-restrictive clause](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/non-restrictive_clauses.htm).

Comment: Thank you @Void, your answer is exactly what I need.